# How can I find my Bug-report on launchpad that I submitted from the Desktop?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, apport

How can I find my Bug-report that I submitted from the Desktop on launchpad?

I have found a partial solution to my own question:

The program that sends the Bug-reports from the desktop is called apport.
It doesn't requires a launchpad account. The service `whoopsie` submits the Bug-Report directly to the server daisy.ubuntu.com
(I'm not sure if those bugs actually appear on launchpad publicly.)

But I found my Bug-Report on my Harddisk in `/var/crash/` .

From there I can copy and paste parts of the file to my opened bug on launchpad.
Thanks for your tips.

*Original question*:

I had a severe bug, and I found someone with the same problem in launchpad. After I found a temporary fix I was able to submit the bug with the ubuntu-bug-reporter.

How can I find this ubuntu-bug-reporter generated bug-report in launchpad?
I would like to combine those two bug-reports (mark as duplicate). Because the generated one has all the debug information and the other one has the description of this bug.

Comment: If you followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), you must have created an account on Launchpad. You should be able to log in and see the bugs you reported.

Comment: IMHO the answers there are not satisfying. It looks like apport/whoopsie/ubuntu-bug reports a bug without a launchpad account, and the provided answers and comment don't tell how to locate/claim it, short of reporting it again with launchpad account.

Comment: You're totally right @StéphaneGourichon. I even forgot about my bug report. But yes, it's still the same problem even 4 years later.

Comment: What you describe here isn't possible; all Launchpad bugs have a linked user account that reported them.  Now, some error reports end up on errors.ubuntu.com, which is a separate thing, but that consists purely of crash reports without any extra descriptive text and it doesn't have any links to users, so I don't think it's what you're thinking of here.  If apport didn't present you with a browser window where you could log into Launchpad and write text about your bug, then it didn't file a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You go to the [your reported bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~/+reportedbugs) page.

Answer (score 3):

If your lp account is also danschel, you can browse your submitted bugs at this page:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/~danschel/+reportedbugs

Use the advanced search to get a [complete list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~danschel/+reportedbugs?field.searchtext=&orderby=-importance&field.status%3alist=NEW&field.status%3alist=OPINION&field.status%3alist=INVALID&field.status%3alist=WONTFIX&field.status%3alist=EXPIRED&field.status%3alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.status%3alist=FIXRELEASED&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&assignee_option=any&field.assignee=&field.bug_commenter=&field.subscriber=&field.structural_subscriber=&field.tag=&field.tags_combinator=ANY&field.status_upstream-empty-marker=1&field.has_cve.used=&field.omit_dupes.used=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.affects_me.used=&field.has_patch.used=&field.has_branches.used=&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches.used=&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints.used=&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints.used=&field.has_no_blueprints=on&search=Search).

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Yes right. At ../+reportedbugs I see the bug I wrote after login on launchpad in the webbrowser.

But I search for the Bug that was submitted by my Ubuntu Installation. Not that one I wrote by myself. 
I think my Ubuntu Installation submitted the bug anonymously. E.g. is there somewhere on my system a log for the transmitted bugs?

Comment: Maybe in `/var/log/apport.log`