# How to make sure an error listed at https://errors.ubuntu.com/ gets a bug report assigned to it?

Tags: crash, launchpad, error-handling, apport

When some program crashes and an automatically generated error report is sent as discussed here [What happens when I click "Send" after Ubuntu experienced an internal error?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1127780/874649) then the error report is added to the info shown at https://errors.ubuntu.com/ where the most frequent errors are shown at the top of the list.

The rightmost column in the list at https://errors.ubuntu.com/ is "Bug report" and for most of the common errors there is a bug report number there, and by clicking on that we can see the status and discussion regarding that bug report, which is great. But for some of the most common errors, the "Bug report" column is empty.

To me it seems like there should be a corresponding bug report for each error, especially for those errors that have hundreds or thousands of occurrences per day. Should I create a bug report in case the "Bug report" column is empty?

If I do that, how can I make sure my bug report is properly linked to the error reports on the https://errors.ubuntu.com/ page?

Edit: as an example, consider the error "seahorse (seahorse) glib-watch.c → 195 → timeout_update → Assertion `!t->dead'' failed." that is currently listed at https://errors.ubuntu.com/ with Rank 9, with 225 occurrences during the past day. This particular error happens on my computer every few days, I usually choose to send an error report so I expect that my reports are then seen as additional occurrences of the error in that list. But there is no linked bug report, which makes me worry that developers of the seahorse package are still not aware of it. The same error has been occurring for more than a year, which also makes me think the developers are unaware of it, otherwise they would have done something about it by now. The question is then, what should be done to make sure there is a bug report what the developers become aware of? Note however that my question is mostly about how this is meant to work in general, this particular seahorse error is just an example, I'm interested in that case but even more interested in understanding how this works in general.

Comment: Some bug reports are private, There may be Personally Identifiable Information in the report (rare), or there might be an undisclosed security issue involved, and other possible reasons.

Comment: In addition to the above, not all reported errors are actually bugs in Ubuntu itself.

Comment: @user535733 thanks, but isn't it also possible that no bug report has been created (or linked to) yet? It looks like tha automatic error reports are created independently and then someone has to do something to link each one to a bug report? See the example I added under "Edit" in the question above.

Comment: @KGIII Of course it's not about "Ubuntu itself", the error is usually in some package but the error tracker is clearly able to link to bug reports for error in different packages. What about the seahorse crash example that I added under "Edit" in the question above?

Comment: If I recall correctly when I looked into this a few years ago, Daisy (the system that receives all the crash reports) does indeed generate private bug reports for all unique reports. It also automatically increments the number of affected users on existing bug reports when a duplicate comes in. A human reviews the bug report and decides whether or not to make the bug report public. That's working from memory, so I may be off on a detail or two. The upshot is that frequent crashes are definitely not ignored. Everybody wants high-priority bugs to get fixed quicker.